# integration tests via spring, hsqldb doesn't recognize "use index"

Tags: spring, integration-testing, hsqldb

I have a spring project with the dao and integration tests for it. For integration tests I am using hsqldb. 
Everything was ok, untill I had to add "USE INDEX" command to my query. The application works fine and fetches records as expected. 
But tests started to faile with SQL exception "Unexpeced token USE in command".

So I am wondering, is there any way to configure htsqldb to recognize "USE INDEX" statement? Thanks

My Dao looks like the following:

```
public interface SomeDao extends CrudRepository<Mapping, Integer> {
@Query(value = "SELECT mm.record_id" +
            " FROM mappings mm" +
            " USE INDEX (mapping_indx)" +
            " JOIN records ss ON mm.record_id = ss.id "
            " WHERE mm.name= :name", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Integer> getRecordsIds(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

My test example:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration("classpath*:testContext.xml")
    public class SimpleTEst{
    @Autowired
    private SomeDao someDao;
//...other daos

    @Test
    public void testDao() {
//...test background creation
      List<Integer> actualList = someDao.getRecordsIds("testing");
      assertEquals(expectedList, actualList);
    }

    }
```

testContext.xml contains the following settings

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myTest"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
```

Comment: The principle of an integration test is to use all the software components used in the real application and to test them together, to gain some assurance that once deployed, the application will work flawlessly. Your integration tests use a database that isn't your production database. So, not only the tests don't pass although they would with the real database, but you gain no assurance at all, because you have no idea if the tests that pass would also pass with the real database. So my advice is: use the real database.

Comment: Thank you for good and clear input, I will migrate to real database in future. But currently, I need to know is there really any way to solve this problem

Comment: I don't this there is a good one. You are using database (in your tests) that is not compatible with your production database - what can change that? :)

Comment: I guess nothing:) thanks for comment, I needed to know that I am not missing something here and there is really nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

different dbs are not compatible so, in general, you can't run same sql on both of them. you have a few quick potential workarounds:

- teach your test database new constructs/functions. in some in-memory dbs you can register new functions. not sure if it's your case
- skip some tests when running on different-vendor-db. if you don't test also on same-vendor-db then this actually mean: remove the test :(
- create/choose query dynamically base on your runtime-detected vendor. this way you can limit tested part of query

to summarize: there is probably absolutely no way to test `use index` on hsqldb. you should test it on real db. if you really want to stick to hsqldb, what you can do is to try to test as similar query as possible... but not the same, sorry

Comment: Thanks for explanation and the list of workarounds, this gives more ways to try, thanks

Comment: Ok, this question may be inappropriate, but just to be sure. so hsqldb just is not able to support all statements of mysql and there is nothing to do about it. Or the reason can be in missing index in in-memory db?

Comment: yes, db X doesn't support all statements supported by db Y